# How to Insert a New Node Using LINQ to XML when only xml data is available?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file with the below structure:

```
<connections>
  <connection>   
    <serverName>serverName1</serverName>
    <dbName>dbName1</dbName>   
  </connection>
</connections>
```

I have a new connection as text data as shown below:

```
var xml="<connection><serverName>serverName2</serverName><dbName>dbName2</dbName></connection>";

var xDocument = XDocument.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(this.XmlDataFilePath));
```

How could I insert this new node to my document?

I tried this but it failed:

```
 xDocument.Root.AddAfterSelf(xml);

 xDocument.Save(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(this.XmlDataFilePath));
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Parse the XML into an XElement and then add that:

```
var element = XElement.Parse(xml);
xDocument.Root.Add(element);
```

Note this is *not* `AddAfterSelf` - you can't add a second root element as the peer of the first one. The code above will add a new *child* element after any existing ones, *within* the root element.

Comment: Great, thanks Jon. Do you know how .NET disposes the connection to the xml file when using LINQ to XML? I mean if you have a multithreading application such as asp.net, when would the resource (this xml file) get released by .NET? e.g. immediately after the .Save() method is called?

Comment: @William: There's no such thing as a "connection to an XML file". An `XDocument` etc doesn't know or care how it was loaded or where it's saved to. The `Save` method will open a file handle, save it, then close the file handle - there's nothing more you need to do.

Comment: Brilliant! I have also added a writeLock so that only one thread can write to the file at a time.